# Trying to make this web crawler print the countdown on this website

Tags: python, function, api, beautifulsoup, request

Trying to make this web crawler print the countdown on the top charts website. However, it doesn't print. I get two brackets as a response so I know that it is getting to the website and pulling data but not pulling the correct data. Thanks.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

meme = input("Number: ")
if meme == "3":
def cd():
    url = 'https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/'
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

    days = [i.text.replace('\n', "") for i in soup.find_all("div#",id="countdown", class_="days", text="count")]
    print(days)
cd()
```

Comment: what is the output from `soup.find_all("div#",id="countdown", class_="days", text="count")`?

Comment: Hi @Edit, please let me know if my solution below helped you to solve the problem or should be further developed.

Answer (score 1):

Countdown container includes a dynamic content that changes second by second. Information retrieved from Javascript and that's why you cannot get it by `requests` library. To get the information, you can use another library called `Selenium`. 
`Selenium` is a web automation tool that helps you to navigate through the webpages and scrape data. 
To install `selenium`:

```
pip install selenium
```

You should install the `chromedriver` to be able to use `webdriver.Chrome`. Install the latest chromedriver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/). Then put the location of the driver to the PATH environment variable. If you do not want to adjust PATH, you can also give the path of the driver to the constructor:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver.exe")
```

Then use this snippet to scrape countdown information.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
meme = input("Number: ")
if meme == "3":
    def cd():
        url = 'https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/'
        driver.get(url)
        
        
        days = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#countdown > .days").text.strip().replace("\n", " ")
        hours = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#countdown > .hours").text.strip().replace("\n", " ")
        minutes = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#countdown > .minutes").text.strip().replace("\n", " ")
        seconds = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#countdown > .seconds").text.strip().replace("\n", " ")
        print(days, hours, minutes, seconds)
    cd()
```